# Зацикливается BrowserSync когда фото в папку добавляешь

Tags: javascript, изображения, gulp

Использую Gulp и при добавлении фото в папку с проектом BrowserSync зацикливается на какое-то время. В чем может быть проблема? Мысль была что я при закидывании фото в папку src каждый раз  все файлы поштучно перекидываю в build папку. Подскажите как мне не все закидывать каждый раз, а то что я закинул в src то и  в buld перекинулось, чтобы не все из src тянулось.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
// Copy Images
gulp.task("copy:img", function (callback) {
    return gulp.src("./src/img/**/*.*").pipe(gulp.dest("./build/img/"));
    callback();
});
```

```
gulp.task("watch", function () {

    watch(
        ["./build/js/**/*.*", "./build/img/**/*.*"],
        gulp.parallel(browserSync.reload)
    );
        
    watch("./src/img/**/*.*", gulp.parallel("copy:img"));

    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение на свой вопрос. Оказалось банально просто, у меня получается отслеживание и build и src картинки и оно зацикливает обе папки при добавлении  картинки в src. Сделал отслеживание src, а в build просто копирование без отслеживания. Но проблема в том что фото не удаляются из build если в src удалил что-то, пока решение перезапустить gulp, чтобы все обновить.

```
gulp.task("watch", function () {

    watch(
        ["./build/js/**/*.*", "./src/img/**/*.*"],
        gulp.parallel(browserSync.reload)
    );
        
    watch("./src/img/**/*.*", gulp.parallel("copy:img"));

   
});
```